# Silencing a Problem in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, lint, tslint

In my project, I have some code that checks which mouse wheel is supported (for different browsers) so we can add an event listener correctly. Here is how it looks:

```
const support = 'onwheel' in document.createElement('div') 
? 'wheel'
: document.onmousewheel !== undefined 
    ? 'mousewheel'
    :'DOMMouseScroll';
```

It works. However, I recently switched over to using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), and there is now a constant *Problem*:

> Property 'onmousewheel' does not exist on type 'Document'.

This is a valid, and useful error. However, in this case I want to ignore it as this is what I am checking for.

[image]

Is there any way I can ignore this *Problem* on this line only? As I am using TypeScript, I have tried `// tslint:disable-line`, but I think this is VS Code itself. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: document['onmousewheel'], (document as any).onmousewheel

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this problem because the built-in TypeScript types for the DOM (often referred to as `lib.dom.d.ts` because of the file name where they're stored) don't declare that the `onmousewheel` property exists on the `Document` type. The global `document` variable is declared as having the type `Document`. However, it does apparently exist on `window`. Can you switch the code to `window.onmousewheel`?

If you're sure you *must* have `document.onmousewheel`, you can make a new file (let's call it `typings/lib.custom.d.ts`) and declare that the `Document` interface also has an `onmousewheel` property:

```
interface Document {
    onmousewheel: ((this: Document, ev: Event) => any) | null;
}
```

*Note that this file cannot `import` or `export` anything: it's meant to declare a globally available interface `Document`, which will add types to any pre-existing globally available interface `Document`.*

Note: trying [`tslint:disable`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/) does nothing here because the errors you're getting are in TypeScript. TSLint provides an additional layer of checking on top of TypeScript, but since this error is itself TypeScript, it's a non-factor. You might be thinking of [`@ts-ignore`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments). However, that should rarely (if ever) be used, and only as a last resort. It's much better to properly inform the type system that something is the way you think it is (like above with the added `onmousewheel` interface property) than to completely disable TypeScript for a line. Disabling TypeScript on a line can ignore other, valid errors.